# Where can I find my car's colour code?

Tags: honda, paint-scratches

I'm currently shopping around for a touch-up pen to repair some very light scratches on my car. I've found out that our local hardware automotive store can mix the exact colour for any vehicle. However, they need the colour code information for my particular car.

How can I obtain the exact colour code? It's a 2010 Honda Jazz (S, 1.2 Petrol), by the way.

Thanks.

Comment: When you say a year old, do you mean 2010?  Can you edit your question so that the exact year, make and model is included?  If someone else with the same car as you comes to this site, your question and the answers below will be more helpful.  Thank you!

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. Edited :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's on a sticker in the drivers door jam

[image]

Examples [here](http://www.automotivetouchup.com/paint-codes/honda.htm), [here](http://www.expresspaint.com/helpful_tips/color_location_guide.asp#acura), and [here](http://www.hondapartsnow.com/guide/honda-color-code.html).

Comment: Usually it's also on a sticker in the glove box.

Answer (score 0):

On mine, a 2012 Honda Jazz Hybrid, the color code in on a metal plate on the passenger side central column (the "B pillar" I think).

[image: Color Code Plate on Honda Jazz]